# I am not getting GET request in URL

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to submit a data set to ESP32 with the help of XML, but when I submit the button it doesn't work. It doesn't even submit a data set.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>




Enter string  <input id="text" type="text" name="input_string">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="test">
<iframe style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></iframe>

<script>
let a;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  let a  = document.getElementById("text").value;
  xhttp.open("GET", `http://192.168.43.154/get?input_string=${a}`, true);
  xhttp.send();
};

</script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: If you are not getting anything back than the URL is bad, the server isn't listening, the server isn't responding because you request is bad (no a usual situation), or server is using TLS and the TLS is failing.

Comment: I figured it out I was missing onclick function in submit button . Thank You